# Use str.join on strs in columns in df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, join

Is there a way to use join here?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a','b','c']
])
df['combined'] = df[0] + ':' + df[1] + ':' + df[2]
df
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df['combined'] = ':'.join([df[0], df[1], df[2]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first way is the most efficient but you can use .str access with cat.

```
df['combined']=df[0].str.cat(df.loc[:, 1:], sep=':')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2 combined
0  a  b  c    a:b:c
```

Other less efficient ways:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x) ,axis=1)
```